# UDPで書かれたコードをTCPに書き直したい

Tags: python, socket, tcp, udp

以下の記事にて紹介されているPythonのUDP通信のサンプルを
TCPに書き直したいです。

[PythonによるUDP通信 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/akakou/items/e9fbcfc0c69cc957152e)

SOCK_DGRAMをSOCK_STREAMに書き換えるだけではエラーが出て動きませんでした。

**TCPSend.py**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

while True:
    msg = 'print("test")\n'
    s.sendto(msg.encode(), (ADDRESS, PORT))
s.close()
```

**TCPRecieve.py**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    msg, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
    exec(msg.decode('utf-8'))

s.close()
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
UDPSend.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.sendto(msg.encode(), (ADDRESS, PORT))
OSError: [WinError 10057] ソケットが接続されていないか、sendto 呼び出しを使ってデータグラム ソケットで送信するときにアドレスが指定されていないため、データの送受信を要求することは禁じられています。
```

SOCK_DGRAM、SOCK_STREAMの箇所以外にどこを書き換えればUDPからTCPにできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

公式ドキュメントにTCPでの送信側と受信側のコード例があります。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/socket.html#example

Answer (score 2):

TDPが、送りっぱなし（データが届いたかどうかの確認ができない）の簡単なプロトコルであるのに対して、TCPは送達確認や分割送信などの機能を持ったちょっと複雑なプロトコルです。

Qiitaの[pythonでsocket通信を勉強しよう](https://qiita.com/__init__/items/5c89fa5b37b8c5ed32a4)の記事の説明が判りやすいと思います。（Pythonのプログラム例もあります）